# How can I migrate a font library?

Tags: 9

I have a Drupal 7 multi-site platform which contains a `sites/all/libraries/fonts/<fontname>` directory, where there are several font files.

I am porting one of the Drupal 7 sites to a new Drupal 9 platform, where I have created a Drupal 9 version of the theme. I want to use these fonts on the Drupal 9 site.

Where should I copy these font files? How do I tell the Drupal 9 theme about them?

Comment: `To where should I copy these D7 font files on the new D9 site` somewhere on your D9 custom theme's folder. `how do I tell the D9 theme about them?` [Add them to your CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't need to update the theme YAML files (`theme.info.yml`, `theme.libraries.yml`) to tell Drupal about the new font, just copying the font directory across to somewhere inside the D9 theme, and referencing it in the CSS was enough, as suggested in the comments.